# Issue using xargs in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, xargs

I am attempting to pipe the output from youtube-dl to `xargs` as I would like to name the downloaded file with the title extracted from the first command. however am having trouble doing so. The command I am using is as follows;

`youtube-dl --get-title "Youtube URI" | xargs youtube-dl -o {} "YouTube URI"`

Comment: Xargs can't deal with spaces ' and " unless you pass the -0 flag. Also, I don't know youtube-dl, but maybe it doesn't take standard input, so xargs would be useless.

Comment: @Bruno9779 - What do you mean by space ' and "? How would I know whether an application like youtube-dl takes standard input?

Comment: I mean the space character, quotes and double quotes. Read the man pages of xargs for more on that and stdi/o (I don't want to paste all that here). It looks like youtube-dl takes only URLs as stdin, so your command can't work IMO. Still, try with a -0 flag after xargs first, you never know

Comment: @Bruno9779: `-0` would produce a file name with the ending newline character in it, which is allowed, but often annoying. If no other delimiter is given with `-d`, `xargs` defaults to `\n` ("newline") which is appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address your specific question about `xargs`, you need to specify that you want to use the `{}` placeholder:

```
youtube-dl --get-title "Youtube URI" |\
    xargs -I{} youtube-dl -o {} "Youtube URI"
```

See `man xargs` for more info, and what switches are also implied by `-I`.

Since it's only a single argument, it would be more straightforward to use substitution:

```
youtube-dl -o "$(youtube-dl --get-title "Youtube URI")" "Youtube URI"
```

**Note** that these constructions will give you a file without appropriate file extension.

The most straightforward way to accomplish your *actual* task would as mentioned be to use the built-in title naming option:

```
youtube-dl -t "Youtube URI"
```

as described in `man youtube-dl`. This will also produce the correct file extension for the video file.

Comment: Thanks. I don't quite follow what you mean by I need to specify that I want to use the {} placeholder. My understanding is that {} is a placeholder for the output produced in the preceding command.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: No, usually `xargs` just appends all incoming arguments after the given command. `echo foo bar | xargs -d' ' echo baz` will print `baz foo bar` on a single line; the arguments have been appended to _a single_ `echo` call. The `{}` placeholder is a special construct, and needs to be explicitly activated with `-I`, as it says in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

I have been reading youtube-dl man pages: what you are trying to do is much simpler than that, you just need the -t,--title flag.

```
youtube-dl --title "Youtube URL"
```

or

```
youtube-dl -t "Youtube URL"
```

http://dev.man-online.org/man1/youtube-dl/

Comment: The reason I want to avoid `youtube-dl --title "YouTube URL" is because it has a different output to that of `youtube-dl --get-title "Youtube URL".